# Meaning of しようとすることができる

Tags: grammar

Please, help!

What is the meaning of

> しようとすることができる

can try to do something?

Let's take the following sentence as an example

> 身近な目標に向かってチャレンジしようとすることができる。

Does it mean

> To focuse on one of the near goals and try to achieve it.

Comment: I was asked to translate this. I don't know the context and the source. So, I am not sure whether this sentence is grammatically correct. It looks weird to me.

Comment: I doubt you are going to reach any meaningful conclusion, because that sentence is gibberish. It looks machine translated, and I have no idea what it means (especially the middle section). It's not impossible to break down a nonsensical sentence, but I don't think that would be useful…

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I suspected that it is gibberish. But what about 

身近な目標に向かってチャレンジしようとすることができる。

and the meaning of

 しようとすることができる

Comment: I have changed the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

〜しようとする can mean “attempt” or “want to do”, and 〜ことができる denotes ability:

> 〜しようとすることができる
>   *to be able to attempt*;
>   *to have the ability to want to do*

I struggle to think of a single situation where this phrase would be used though. Maybe when describing the developmental stages of a child? (e.g. 口に指を入れようすることができる *have the ability to want to put fingers in their mouths*)

---

#### チャレンジしようとする

This seems like a redundant phrase, similar to saying “attempt to try”. I'm not sure whether this is intentional, or if it is just a poorly considered way of saying チャレンジする.

Preserving the redundancy, the sentence would be translated as:

> 身近な目標に向かってチャレンジしようとすることができる
>   *have the ability to attempt/want to try to achieve a near-term goal*